# Optimizing app notifications for Android 6.0

Tags: android, permissions, notifications

My app was built to run on Android 4.0 - 5.1 and ran fine.

With release of Anroid 6.0 issues with notifications began to emerge.

Following screenshots pinpoint default settings that need to be set to true in order to make the app work correctly.

Could you please point me to tutorial that discusses these system settings as I was unable to find any relevant information about these topics.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Those are manufacturer specific settings, you should contact the manufacturer.

Comment: I may be wrong but I'm going to suggest that those are manufacturer settings that Android doesn't want one to change, as to give the user more control. Maybe you can change those things but it hurts the user experience, if the user sets those settings one way they expect them to stay.

Comment: @ianhanniballake all major players, Facebook, Whatsapp and such have those enabled by default right after install to make notifications work properly.

Comment: @ShadowGod these settings need to be enabled because push notifications do not appear once an app is closed from multitasking. Also when app is in stand by in multitasking, notifications only appear in status bar, not as banners nor in lock screen. That would be a major turn off for Facebook.

Comment: Yes, the manufacturer can choose to allow some apps by default. You'd need to talk to them

Comment: @ianhanniballake oh thats very inconvenient. This means my push notifications wont work unless the user specifically enables these settings manually? Its a messaging app.